# Dates prior to Jan 2, 1884 show as a day prior in Angular2 Date pipe

Tags: javascript, date, angular, typescript

I'm collecting dates from a simple HTML `date` input field with the following code:

`new Date(Number(dateString.substring(0,4)), Number(dateString.substring(5,7))-1, Number(dateString.substring(8,10)))`

...and I output these dates to the user with this code:

`startDate?((startDate | date | uppercase)`

This works fine for ANY DATE AFTER January 1, 1884.  So, January 2, 1884 works fine (and any date to today from what I can tell), but if I enter January 1, 1884 it is displayed back as December 31, 1883.  Any date prior to January 1, 1884 has the same issue.

I get that it will be converting this back into my local timezone when displayed, but that problem should manifest itself for all dates (I've already encountered that).  What happened on January 1, 1884?  Why is this date special?

I also notice that if I go WAY back, to January 1, 0100 - a day gets added.  So that day becomes January 2, 0100.

I am not sure exactly where the crossover happens there but certainly something funny is going on.  If I just output the value of the date to the console I correctly get:

`1884-01-01T08:00:00.000Z`

...and for the 2nd of that month I get, predictably:

`1884-01-02T08:00:00.000Z`

So it seems like it is the Angular2 `date` pipe that is changing it.  Is this a bug or am I doing something incorrectly (which is believable)?

Comment: In which browser? Safari has issues with dates, particularly around daylight saving changeover. What is the format of *dateString*? There is no need for `Number(...)`.

Comment: ...so first, for `Number(...)` - I'm using Typescript so I get an error in my IDE if I don't include that.  Yes it runs fine either way, and if the string is just directly taken from the JSON object it is fine, but I'm passing it into a utility function that takes in a string.

Comment: For the error - I get it in Chrome: 47.0.2526.106 and Safari: 12602.1.50.0.10.  Here's the funny thing I just noticed - identical code base running on two servers.  From one computer BOTH servers produce the CORRECT behaviour using either browser, and on the other computer BOTH servers produce the INCORRECT behaviour using either browser.  I can make no sense of that at all.  Both are OS X 10.12.  Same browser versions.  I realize that is hard to believe, but that's where I'm at.  I guess I'll try a few other computers.  Localization settings?  ...but the question remains - why Jan 1, 1884?

Comment: Localization settings are now identical on both systems.  No difference.  I can't explain this.  I may just restrict users from entering dates prior to 1885!  I understand that someone reading this would think I'm just making an error but I've had other developers take a look and try it themselves in person.  They are amused by the fact I'm the one having to fix this bug, but it is a real thing!

Comment: Regarding `Number(...)`, that is an unnecessary restriction, but there you go. Can't help with the rest, unfortunately I've come to seriously distrust dates in javascript in general. There is too much weirdness, hard to believe for such a simple object.

Comment: consider using `moment` and creating a `MomentPipe` it is quite helpful. Obviously that is not what you asked about but, as @RobG says, built in Dates are a trainwreck...