# Moment parse zone gives unexpected result

Tags: date, timezone, momentjs

```js
const input = '02/02/1700 12:30'
const inputFormat = ['DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm']
const displayFormat = 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss'


console.log(moment(input, inputFormat, true))
console.log(moment(input, inputFormat, true).format())
console.log(moment.utc(input, inputFormat, true))
console.log(moment.utc(input, inputFormat, true).format())
console.log(moment.parseZone(input, inputFormat, true))
console.log(moment.parseZone(input, inputFormat, true).format())
console.log(moment.tz(input, inputFormat, true, 'Asia/Hong_Kong'))
console.log(moment.tz(input, inputFormat, true, 'Asia/Hong_Kong').format())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.31/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y9gtvbdn/

The above example the result of parseZone give `1700-02-02T12:29:18Z` which is different from input `'02/02/1700 12:30'`. Anyone can explain this to me?

Comment: Hi.  Please don't just link to external code.  You can use an external site to *supplement* your question, but you need to include the specific code you are asking about in the question itself.  Please read [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [*How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the Stack Overflow help center.  Thanks.  (Also, there's too much in your fiddle anyway - limit your code to the specific question - remove the parts that aren't relevant.)

Comment: Just want to show different cases. Anyway, I suspect this is a moment bug.

Comment: Updated with the code anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

- Don't log a `moment` directly.  Always use an output function like `format`
- When you parse in Moment, internally Moment is calling setters on a `Date` object.  Since you aren't passing seconds or milliseconds, the setter for that is never called.  If you *did* have seconds, you'd see them set to zero as expected.
- The reason that they aren't in this case is that there's a longstanding *browser* bug with `Date` objects constructed on or before `1883-11-18T12:03:57.999Z`.  See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51159704/chrome-javascript-date-constructor-appears-to-get-dates-before-1884-wrong?noredirect=1#comment89304745_51159704), and the associated question.  This isn't a moment bug, but a JavaScript browser quirk.  This only matters for very early dates.
- `parseZone` is specifically for use when the input *has* a time zone offset in it - either numeric like `-07:00` or a `Z` (which indicates UTC).  Your example input string has neither in it.